# About the use of "pretty"

Tags: adverbs

Can I use "pretty" as a degree adverb to describe an adjective that has a negative meaning?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's perfectly acceptable. "Pretty ugly" is quite a common phrase, and there's a punk rock song, "We're ... pretty vacant".

Comment: This would be a better question if you gave an example.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/pretty-fairly-really-very-and-quite), you can, pretty has a similar meaning to fairly, quite, and somewhat.